# Using HTML.EditFor for an viewmodel inside a parent viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm new to MVC3 and razor so this might be obvious but no amount of googlefu has found an answer for me.

I have a ViewModel called user, inside of user i have a 2nd viewmodel called address.

Address is used all over the place so i planned on having the following\

ViewModels:

1. User -> {Fname, lname, Address}
2. Business -> {companyname, Address}
3. House -> {Number, Address}
4. Address -> {addyline1, addyline2, city, state, zip}

Ala...
user.address.addyline1, business.address.addyline1

All of these will have the Address inside them.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.address)
```

Works fine but doesn't use the template I have created in

> views->shared->editortemplate->address.cshtml

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.address, "Address")
```

Does not work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @jbtule. just remove the file extension from the partial view's name and you should be fine.

Another thing you can do to control how your `Address` objects get rendered without having to specify the partial view template every time is create what's called an `EditorTemplate`. Here's how you do it:

Create a folder called `EditorTemplates` under the `Views->Shared` folder in your ASP.NET MVC solution.
In that folder, create a strongly typed view whose name matches the name of the type you want the editor for (in your case it should be called `Address.cshtml`), and you can also set the scaffolding template to `Edit` to have a ready-to-go editor generated for you. and you're all set! all is left is to have add

here's an [example](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/02/05/mvc-2-editor-template-with-datetime.aspx) on how to do this (note that it uses ASP.NET MVC2, and of course, the ASPX view engine, however the idea is the same).

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Tried that, neither work: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.address, "~/Views/Shared/_AddressPartial.cshtml") as well as @Html.EditorFor(model => model.address, "_AddressPartial")

Comment: I guess the problem might be elsewere, I've tried both approaches (before posting), and both worked just fine :s

Comment: I ended up making a project from scratch. I just copied and pasted the files from the old one to the new one and everything worked. I've done it multiple times now and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well you don't use put "cshtml" portion in typically when you put the template name probably `"_AddressPartial"` would work for you, but i'd think you want to just omit that argument and put your custom razor template in "~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/address.cshtml"

Answer (score 1):

The name of the folder to place your `Address.cshtml` is

```
EditorTemplates
```

and not `EditorTemplate` (one small `s` can make a lot of difference).